# Databinding within Cell templated DataGrid not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I try to bind a `List<string>` property `SubscribedSymbols` within a class object `StrategySubscription` as part of `List<StrategySubscription>` to comboboxes in each cells of a specific column in a DataGrid but cannot get the data binding to work.

The auto column generator works and populates values onto the grid. So, I am sure the data exists.

I attached the xaml code and data object as well as a screenshot of the current output.

Can you please help to get the data binding to work correctly? I want the collection of strings within `SubscribedSymbols` to be populated in the comboboxes of each cell in the templated column.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StrategySubscriptions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy ID" Binding="{Binding StrategyId}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy Name " Binding="{Binding StrategyName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy Capitalization" Binding="{Binding CapitalAllocation}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Symbol Subscriptions" ItemsSource="{Binding SubscribedSymbols, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

public class StrategySubscription
    {
        public Guid StrategyId { get; set; }
        public string StrategyName { get; set; }
        public int CapitalAllocation { get; set; }
        public List<string> SubscribedSymbols { get; set; }

        public StrategySubscription(string strategyName, Guid strategyId, int capitalAllocation, List<SymbolSubscription> symbolSubscriptions)
        {
            StrategyName = strategyName;
            StrategyId = strategyId;
            CapitalAllocation = capitalAllocation;
            SubscribedSymbols = symbolSubscriptions.Select(x => x.Symbol.SymbolId).ToList();
            //SubscribedSymbols = String.Join(", ", symbolSubscriptions.Select(x => x.Symbol.SymbolId).OrderBy(x=>x));
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Symbol Subscriptions" >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SubscribedSymbols}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SubscribedSymbols}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
...
```

Comment: thank you that works perfectly. Would you mind taking a look at the following please? I try to accomplish the same for a DevExpress Gridcontrol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783582/databinding-within-cell-templated-devexpressgridcontrol-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Try using template column to have more control over it:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Symbol Subscriptions">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubscribedSymbols}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The reason of the problem is that DataGridColumns are not part of the visual tree. See more explanation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx

Comment: thank you that works perfectly. Would you mind taking a look at the following please? I try to accomplish the same for a DevExpress Gridcontrol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783582/databinding-within-cell-templated-devexpressgridcontrol-not-working (P.S.: I had to in the end choose the answer by time submitted as I find them equally good).